# Creating network listener on glassfish causing to bomb on startup

Tags: servlets, ssl, https, glassfish-3

I have a network listener that i listening to port 8181 for one website www.aaaa.com that is securely accessing a module aaa.war on my glassfish server.  I have another website www.bbbb.com that is also to be securely accessing a module bbb.war on a glassfish server.  I have created a virtual server for each module but each server has its own secure SSL ticket.  In glassfish as far as I can tell each listener can only have one certificate nickname.  So thusly i need two listeners...but if i create a network listener for the virtual server www.bbb.com to use, it fails when i restart glassfish cause that second network listener also needs to listen on 8181 doesn't it?  so it says the port is binded and in use.  Is there some critical step I am missing to using network listeners in glassfish and virtual servers?

I believe the issue has something to do with what is brought up here:

http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/glassfish-301-cannot-be-configured-use-ssl-certificates-different-internet-domain-names

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Glassfish does not support yet **SNI** (Server Name Indication) a new TLS feature that allows to indicate the host name during SSL handshaking. So now you can only have one certificate per port.

See [this JIRA ticket](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17934). If you want you can vote this issue up.

Anyway, if you have multiple ip addresses you can create multiple listeners for the same port and then bind multiple SSL certificates.

Comment: thanks did some more reading it looks like I have to have multiple IP addresses to connect multiple listeners to.

Comment: Yes, one only listener per port/IP

Comment: so it sounds like that box will need multiple IP addresses for every app that uses a secure connection?

Comment: @Codejoy. If you have two ip addresses you can create two listeners, one per virtual server, and then set two SSL certificate.

Comment: Thanks again I am begginging to grasp all this.  Looks ilke mod_proxy might be another path using apache to front the requests?

Comment: @Codejoy: I think so. Moreover Apache httpd 2.3+ has SNI so you can have two certificates for the same port.